# Libvirt memory management host and guest

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtual-machine, qemu, memory-management

I have set up two guest oses a ubuntu box dedicated to be a vm host. It has two physical cpus (with 6 cores each), 16 GB RAM, and 3 harddisks. Host os is on a 60GB SSD, while the guest oses are on their separate HDD partitioned into two partitions. First partition holds a raw qcow image file for the guest os, and the second partition is assigned as a block device to the guest. (for "programs" and "data") I have memory ballooning enabled on the linux guest, but not on the windows.

I had my first out of memory experience just yesterday, so I decided to watch memory usage of guests real time on my own computer. So I have two htops running in two putty windows, as you can see on the attached picture. On top of the picture is the host, at the bottom is one of the guests (the linux) There are couple of things that I do not understand:

- on the host the RES column says 5778M for the first guest and 4274M for the other, which to me ads up to ~10G, but the Mem line at the top of picture says 6.9G which is strange, furthermore the client htop at the bottom says that 560M memory is in use. (560M != 5778M)

I have read the redhat docs about virtualization, and that say I should calculate the amount of ram needed to the guest by adding up the memory allocated to the guest + Video RAM + "some" overhead (which can not be determined exactly) So using the above numbers: 560M is in use by the guest + 16M video memory is ~580M, so the "some" overhead in my case is 5.2G?

The 5778M is not the total memory the linux guest can use, 8G is set in the domain xml file, so I am not frustrated. Yet.

When I restarted the linux guest this morning it started with ~2G RAM usage on the host and it has been climbing ever since. The guest os started with ~450M and went to 560M.

I even read that assigning a swap file to the host can help with out of memory issues, so I have created a 32G swapfile, and have set swapiness to 20 in sysctl on the host.

But I still do not understand that memory usage / allocation / whatever between the guest and the host.

Could someone with more experience in this field point me in the right direction / tutorial / wikipedia / whatevertoread?
[qemu host guest htops](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BhNVN.png)